# Module importing in Python - performance

Tags: python

The "normal" way of importing packages/modules in Python (and in the most popular programming languages) is to write an import sentence e.g. `import math` at the start of your newly created Python module.

What happens if we import another module within a method (we are using this method multiple times), will interpreter import our module (definitions and statements) again? Will this affect the performance of our program?

So in short, what is the performance-wise difference between:

```
import math

def int_square(n):
    return int(math.sqrt(n))
```

and:

```
def int_square(n):
    import math
    return int(math.sqrt(n))
```

Edit:
I just tested this out with the following lines of code:

```
import time
import math

def calculate(n):
    return math.sqrt(n)
def calculate2(n):
    import math
    return math.sqrt(n)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    calculate(3)
t2 = time.time()

print(t2 - t1)

t1 = time.time()
for i in range(1000000):
    calculate2(3)
t2 = time.time()

print(t2 - t1)
```

The output (on i3 3rd-gen processor)

```
calculate()  -> 0.444s 
calculate2() -> 1.500s
```

Comment: So my theory was proven correct?

Comment: It was, but I still don't see why this was marked as duplicate. Thank you, sir!

Comment: I agree, one should always understand the underlying principles of a language including efficiency and performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Think about it. If you're calling a method multiple times, it's pointless to import the module every time within the method as opposed to once. It is simply more efficient and more logical.

Comment: You are right. But does importing the same module N-times affect the performance?

Comment: I believe it does. Not significantly, but there is an efficiency performance.

Comment: Yes, I just tried it. A program constantly importing in an infinite while loop consumes 8 percent of CPU usage whereas a single import and a while loop consumes 6 percent.

Comment: @MalikBrahimi try doing profiling instead of looking at CPU usage. Once a module is imported, it's imported, and further attempts to import it into the same namespace are pretty much ignored.

Comment: How do I profile in Windows?

Comment: @MattDmo Check my edit on my question, it is clear that repeated importing causes bad performance, but why isn't interpreter saving recently imported modules just in case of repeated use?